# What does this mean in the offer letter

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

In my offer letter:

> $XX,XXX is being offered as "for Spring and Fall semester for the year 20XX"

Here what do they mean? Is $XX,XXX being offered on a per month basis or for the whole year?

Comment: To my knowledge, within the US, i think it is bi-monthly (every two weeks).

Comment: You should ask the graduate office (or whoever sent you the offer letter) for clarification, but from the wording, it appears that this is a 9-month TA contract- you'd be free to do something else over the summer, or there might be additional support available for the summer that you would have to apply for separately.

Comment: There is no way to know. The $MMM could be paid weekly, biweekly, monthly, per semester, or yearly. It could be for 9 months or 12 months. Only way to know is to ask (or ignore it and see what happens).

Comment: Typically you'd be paid  $MMM/18 every two weeks during the 9-month academic year.  $MMM would typically be somewhere in the range from $18,000 to $30,000 for nine months, depending on the institution and the local cost of living.

Comment: Whether it is paid monthly or every two weeks is completely dependent on the institution - there is no standard, even within the US.

Comment: My experience in the US was that we were paid monthly for 12-months but with a 9-month contract. Ask for clarification but you might also be able to request a specific pay schedule.

Comment: No- that's definitely not the case. We were paid (pre-tax) a little over $27,000 on a 9-month contract, but it was paid in 12 monthly increments. After taxes and around $2000/yr in fees and health insurance premiums it came out to around $1,800 a month. I would suggest asking to talk to one or two current graduate students who are willing to answer questions about their finances, such a request was pretty common in my department and we would also have a financial question/answer session with the new students every year.

Comment: Could you edit the question to roughly state the value of $MMM, to within an order of magnitude? You had previously mentioned it in a comment, but it seems to have been removed.  It is important in order for the question to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, $MMM is on the order of US$20,000.  This is almost certainly the stipend for one academic year.

It will probably be paid in monthly or semimonthly installments, over 9 or 12 months.